# How to get WIFI at my home for an Ipod use?

Tags: madwifi

I have ubuntu at my home with 2 desk tops, 1 is a mac, both are wired to t How can I get wifi at my house to use with an Ipod and other things?

Comment: Could you add a little bit more info to your setup?

Comment: If one of the machines has a wireless card, you could set up an ad-hoc network.

Answer (score 1):

The easiest solution would be to get a wireless router, share your internet with other computers on whichever connection you have from the pc to the router, and then connect your ipod to your router via wifi.